# Is there a way to formally handle ellipses, which are ubiquitously used in human-level mathematics? $X_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} X_2 \xrightarrow{f_2} ...$

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, induction, definition, type-theory

For a use case, I want to formally and visually define what a *path* is in a graph.  My definition will allow duplicates of vertices.

So, an inductive definition might start:

$$
X_1 : \text{Path} \\
X_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} X_2 : \text{Path} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
X_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} X_2 : \text{Path} \\
X_2 \xrightarrow{f_2} X_3 : \text{Path}
\end{pmatrix} \implies X_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} X_2 \xrightarrow{f_2} X_3 : \text{Path}
$$

But to handle the general inductive step, it seems like we need ellipses:

$$
X_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} \dots \xrightarrow{f_n} X_{n+1} : \text{Path}
$$

But then we have to define what "$\dots$" means when it occurs "as an arrow" or between two arrows.   How do we do this, or is there a better way to inductively define what a Path is?

Comment: Can you expand on what kind of formalisation you're looking for? A path of edges in a digraph (so, a morphism in the free category over that graph) can be defined inductively, starting from the idea that a path is either empty, or a loop around a vertex, or the concatenation of a path with a vertex, using an edge of the graph. So, no need to formalise the idea of "and so on" expressed by ellipses.

Comment: @fosco I know there's no need, but I want to.  How can it be done?  I only need ellipses for paths for now, so the formalization I'm looking for is one that involves paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much as a list of elements of $A$ can be defined as "either the empty list or the concatenation of a list and an element of $A$", so too a path from $X$ to $Y$ can be defined as "either an empty path from $X$ to $X$, or a path from $X$ to $Y$ concatenated with an edge from $Y$ to $Z$ (which is a path from $X$ to $Z$)".

More formally, these can be written as [*inductive types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_type), which are common in type theory, but not hard to define in set theory by using recursion to produce a series of sets and then taking their union.

The syntax I'll be using is that of [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq). You can read a statement like `A: Type` as saying "let $A$ be a set" and then `a: A` reads "let $a$ be a member of $A$".

So a list of elements of A is

```
Inductive List (A: Type) :=
| nil: List A
| cons (u: List A) (a: A): List A.
```

The elements of `List A` are then things like `nil`, `cons nil a`, `cons (cons nil a) b`, etc. (if `a` and `b` are elements of `A`).

The type of paths is

```
Inductive Path (V: Type) (E: V -> V -> Type): V -> V -> Type
| empty (x: E): Path x x
| conc (x y z: E) (p: Path x y) (e: E y z): Path x z.
```

Where I've taken `E` to be a function that takes two vertices and returns the set of edges between them (if you only allow at most one edge, you can take `E` as returning a set with at most one element).

If `x` and `y` are vertices and `exy: E x y` and `eyx: E y x` are edges, then `Path x y` will consist of `conc (empty x) exy`, `conc (conc (conc (empty x) exy) eyx) exy`, etc. If those are the only edges, each path from `x` to `y` will have an odd number of edges.

Comment: How would you work in the syntax of ellipses?  You can use a pseudo language, so if Coq doesn't support that, then what would it look like if it did.

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder Ellipses by themselves are ambiguous (e.g. the next element in $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 \ldots$ can arguably be either [$64$](https://oeis.org/A000079) or [$63$](https://oeis.org/A006261) (and probably much more)). You wouldn't want to have ellipses in your syntax at all. Instead, you make what the ellipses mean precise and then just use that.

Comment: Yes, but in the case of $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n$ the human automatically knows we mean $1, 2, 3, 4, \dots, n$.  So in my software it will simply auto-recognize that.  Notice, that the formula for the sequence is given by the last entry $n$.  So if instead the sequence were say even numbers, then the sequence for even numbers would end in their formula $2n, k = n$.  So if it's an infinite sequence, then my software will expect: $0, 2, 4, \dots, 2k, \dots$ or two ellipses used.